# date format issue facing while retrieving and populate dates/comments in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have passed full calendar's "start" and "end" date as Java.Util.Date in rest resource service and got saved into Activeobject. 
Now, when i retrieve dates then it shows as follow "2013-04-10 00:00:00.0" in rest resource service.
But in javascript, response shows me 1364927400000 number instead of "2013-04-10 00:00:00.0" so, these dates are not highiligted with added comments in full calendar.

Do i need to cast or how i could resolve this issue ?
My jquery stuff as below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: lnk,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "",
    cache: false,
    success: function (resp, status, xhr) {

        alert(resp[i].start);
...
```

Comment: when retrieving make sure our date doesn't has the microsecond part e.g. it should be 2013-04-10 00:00:00 not 2013-04-10 00:00:00.0

Comment: Maybe you would like to check weather the returning value is a UNIX timestamp, which is the seconds (in JS case the microsconds) since 01.01.1970. Try to convert it back to a Date using `date=new Date(timestamp)` for more info on Unix-Timestamp see: http://www.unixtimestamp.com

Comment: @slevon It works.. i have just added date = new Date(response timestamp) in javascript success events so, it was in unix timestamp in JS even though it is in date format in rest service response. Thank you for quick response.. Add comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is the answer:
Maybe you would like to check weather the returning value is a UNIX timestamp, which is the seconds (in JS case the microsconds) since 01.01.1970. 
Try to convert it back to a Date using

```
  var date=new Date(timestamp)
```

for more info on Unix-Timestamp see:

http://unixtimestamp.com

So hope this helps,
slevon

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net Web API service, the dates would return as "/Date(1586583441106)/" instead of a number, it needs to convert as a number to make it work for javascript.

```
//val dateString = "/Date(1586583441106)/" 
function getDateFromAspNetFormat(dateString) {
    var unformatedDate = dateString.substring(6, dateString.length - 2);
    //console.log(unformatedDate);
    return parseInt(unformatedDate);
}

var formattedDate = new Date(getDateFromAspNetFormat("/Date(1586583441106)/"));
```